# Show entire record from table with minimum timestamp in a group

Tags: sql, group-by

I have been trying for about three hours to solve this problem but cannot find the solution.

How would I show the entire row (all 20 columns) for the first occurance (minimum time) of each name in my table?

For example, I would like to do something like this, which does not work:

```
SELECT name, MIN(time), col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM table
GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to first get the minimum time for each name, and then join back to your original table where the name/time matches.

To get the minimum time:

```
SELECT name, MIN(time) AS minTime
FROM myTable
GROUP BY name;
```

Then, get all columns:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM myTable m
JOIN(
   SELECT name, MIN(time) AS minTime
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY name) tmp ON tmp.name = m.name AND tmp.minTime = m.time;
```

Comment: I am running the query now using both answers, i'll let you know when it is finished

Comment: This script did EXACTLY what I needed, THANKS! took about 25 minutes to run. I am curious of the runtime for the script below

Comment: @OrinMoyer I'm glad I could help. If this is the solution you stick with, you can upvote and/or accept the answer to let future readers know what solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Most databases support ANSI standard window functions.  With these, you can just do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by time) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```